# On change copy value selected option function after page load not working

Tags: jquery, html

I've already lost about some hours with this. I have a working example, i tried whatever I could to replicate the effect on my server-side generated html page from Java JSP.

So basically I use this:

```
<select name="slct" id="slct">
<option value="" selected="selected">select something</option>
<option value="2">One</option>
<option value="3">Two</option>
</select>
```

and this script

```
$("#slct").change(function() {
var textval = $(":selected",this).val();
$('input[name=printit]').val(textval);
});
```

here it outputs :

```
<input type="text" name="printit" id="printit"/>
```

This part of the code works.

But my JSP scriptlet generated code which returns this :

```
<select name="slct" id="slct">
    <option value="" selected="selected">select </option>
    <option value="2">Alex</option>
   <option value="4">Domy</option>
  <option value="5">Luka</option>
</select>
```

With the same javascript code (i deleted the first select while trying this one) doesn't work.

Does it have something to do with those options being server generated -vs javascript ??

What can I do?

Comment: I try your code and it works. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manassornpn/h3Lwrrkd/). Did you miss `$(document).ready(function() { ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content is generated after the script's execution, so the select you generated has no event attached. You can use delegate to solve the problem.

```
$(document).on("click", "#slct", function() {
    var textval = $(":selected",this).val();
    $('input[name=printit]').val(textval);
});
```

Comment: I regret not using this page before to ask the question. I've literally spent from 3 to 6 hours on this. You are a genius. Thank you!